# matplotlib imshow -- use any vector as axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I would like to use any vector as an axis in `plt.imshow()`.

```
A = np.random.rand(4, 4)
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 8])
y = np.array([-1, 0, 2, 3])
```

I imagine something like this:

```
plt.imshow(a, x_ax=x, y_ax=y)
```

I know there is an `extent` parameter available, but sadly it does not allow for non-equally spaced vectors.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imshow plots are always equally spaced. The question would be if you want to have
**(a)**  an equally spaced plot with unequally spaced labels, or
**(b)**  an unequally spaced plot with labels to scale.

#### (a) equally spaced plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.rand(4, 4)
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 8])
y = np.array([-1, 0, 2, 3])

plt.imshow(a)
plt.xticks(range(len(x)), x)
plt.yticks(range(len(y)), y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### (b) unequally spaced plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.rand(3, 3)
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 8])
y = np.array([-1, 0, 2, 3])
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,a)

plt.xticks(x)
plt.yticks(y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that in this case the "vector" would specify the edges of the grid, thus they would only allow for a 3x3 array.

Comment: Is it possible to plot it with specified grid centres instead of the edges?

Comment: How would that work? If you only know the grid centers, how could you know how large a cell is (if you don't assume all cells to be equally sized)?

Comment: Okay, I take it that this cannot work in case of `plt.pcolormesh`, but it is shame that it is not possible for `plt.imshow`.

Comment: The imshow plot does have the pixels centered at the grid positions. What exactly do you mean that is not possible with imshow?